# Difficulties with implementing persian calendar rules with Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a code that somehow resembles the Persian calendar. there are 3 drop down lists for year, month and day. Here are the rules I'd like to include:

- Months 1 to 6 have 31 days
- Months 7 to 11 have 30 days
- Month 12 has 29 days every 4 years
- 12th month has 30 days (leap year)

If the user chooses one of the (1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6) months, the drop down list for days must have 31 days.

If the user chooses one of the (7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 ) months, the drop down list for days must have 30 days.

If the user chooses the 12th month, the drop down list for days must have 29 days.

If the user chooses one of (1375 – 1379 – 1383 – 1387 – 1391 – 1395) year and if he chooses the 12th month, the drop down list for days must have 30 days.

Here is the code I have written so far but my code doesn't work, please help me with it.

```
from tkinter import *

x=StringVar()

def ok():
    if months == months[0:5]:
     x = dayoptions1
    if months == months[6:10]:
     x = dayoptions2
    if months == months[11] and years == 1375 or 1379 or 1383 or 1387 or 1391 or 1395:
     x = dayoptions3


root = Tk()

label1 = Label(root, text="year",width=15)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

yearoptions = ["1397", "1396","1395","1394","1393","1392","1391","1390","1389","1388","1387","1386","1385","1384","1383","1382","1381","1380","1379","1378","1377","1376","1375"]
yearvariable = StringVar(root)
yearvariable.set(yearoptions[0])

years = OptionMenu(root, yearvariable, *yearoptions)
years.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)

label2 = Label(root, text="month",width=15)
label2.grid(row=0, column=2)

monthoptions = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
monthvariable = StringVar(root)
monthvariable.set(monthoptions[0])

months = OptionMenu(root, monthvariable, *monthoptions)
months.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)

label1 = Label(root, text="day",width=15)
label1.grid(row=0, column=4)

dayoptions1 = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"]
dayoptions2 = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"]
dayoptions3 = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29"]
dayvariable = StringVar(root)
dayvariable.set("1")

days = OptionMenu(root, dayvariable, *x)
days.grid(row=0,column=5,padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't explain what is it that doesn't work, but in any case the in the condition `years == 1375 or 1379 or 1383 or 1387 or 1391 or 1395` you probably meant `years in ("1375", "1379", "1383", "1387", "1391", "1395")`.

Comment: when I choose a month from the "months" drop down list, I want my "days" drop down list to change accordingly:
the conditions that I want are mentioned and I that's what I need my function to do. but I don't know how to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I don't tkinter, so I wrote a function but it works. Days depends on what month & year user choose. So scenario is, user choose 1383 - 12 (Year 1383 of Month 12), you need to find if 1383 is a leap year and then fill up the day list with 30 days, or else it would be 29 days. If use choose between month 1 to 6, fill the array with 31 days and the rest of the month has 30 days. I have written a short helper function to check this out and I think it works.

```
def persian_calender():
    user_input = input("year - month:: ")
    date_list = user_input.split("-")
    leap_year = [1375, 1379 ,1383, 1387 ,1391 ,1395]
    year = int(date_list[0])
    month = int (date_list[1])

    if year in leap_year:
        is_leap = True
    else:
        is_leap = False

    if month >= 1 and month <= 6:
        number_of_days = "31"
    elif month >= 7 and month <= 11:
        number_of_days = "30"
    else:
        if is_leap:
            number_of_days = "30"
        else:
            number_of_days = "29"
     print ("Year: " + date_list[0] + " Month: "+ date_list[1] + " Days: "
       + number_of_days)
```

Check the [code file in here](https://pastebin.com/CGA1rquB)

Hope it helps. Cheers!

**[Edit 2]**  
You wrote a helper function  Ok  that finds out what month it is. Instead writing your list manually, just declare the number of days in there. When you want to or it's time to fill up the drop down list of days, run and fill up the list with equivalent number of days.  *Do I make sense?!*

Comment: there is indentation problem

Comment: I provided a url. Check that.

Comment: thanks a lot
how can I use your function in my code?
clearly I can't use a function as the third argument
days = OptionMenu(root, dayvariable, *persian_calender)
cause I get errors

what is the third argument??

Comment: @E.akhavan, did u find a solution?